# Can all sets in stratified L above some stage be proximate?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructibility

Define *stratified* $L$, denoted by $^S L$, as:

Let $S$ be the set of all stratified formulas in first order language of set theory.

*Define:*

${ }^S Def (X) = \{\{y \in X \mid (X, \in) \models \phi(y,z_1,..,z_n) \} \mid \phi \in S \land z_1,..,z_n \in X\}$

*Define*

$${}^S L_0=\varnothing \\ {}^S L_{\alpha+1} = {}^S Def(L_\alpha) \\ {}^S L_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} {}^S L_\alpha $$ Now $${ }^S L = \bigcup_{\alpha \in Ord} { }^S L_\alpha$$ Now define two kinds of ranking functions: $\rho^\subset; \rho^\in$ as:

$\rho^\subset (x) = \min \alpha: x \subseteq  { }^S L_\alpha \\ \rho^\in(x)= \min \alpha: x \in { }^S L_\alpha$

Now for all elements of ${}^S L$ define the one place predicate symbol *proximate* as:

Define: $ prox(x) \iff \rho^\in(x)= \rho^\subset (x) + 1$

If $\rho^\in(x) > \rho^\subset (x) + 1 $, then $x$ to be called *distant*.

> is it consistent with the definition of $^SL$ to have some stage $^S L_\alpha$ such that all sets in stratified stages above it are proximate?